# Delete button in For loop table content

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm having an issue completing a task given by my superior. Namely, I've created a table and completed sorting by rating and managed to make a working add content button. But I hit the wall with trying to add delete button next to every object in the table.

Comment: Add your html and working code

Comment: Hi! Iit's done. I hope everyone get's what I'm looking for. I'm a 10 days javascritp newbie. Only got like 3 days to see into some online courses. After 3 days I'm being thrown into the "fire".

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then you might want to create the buttons directly during the creation of the table. In the HTML you need to create another  with an appropriate title, e.g. "actions"

Then you need to adapt the functions addTableRow and loadTableData where you add a  after the last  containing a button with e.g. an onclick event calling a function "deleteRow(i)" where i is equivalent to the id of the array element you are creating.

Then you change the  element in both of these functions to also have an id="rowi" where "i" in "rowi" once again is the id of the corresponding array element in the list.

```
txt = txt + `<tr id="row`+i+`"><td>${movieData[i].name}</td><td>${movieData[i].genre}</td><td>${movieData[i].rating}</td><td><button value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(`+i+`)"></tr>`;
```

Do not forget to adapt this line accordingly for the addTableRow function so that the i corresponds to the next id inserted into the table.

Lastly you create a function deleteRow(rowid) which deletes the whole  where id is rowid.

```
function deleteRow(rowid) {
  document.getElementById(rowid).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you need a `delete` button for every row of movies. If so, you need to create a button in the `loadTableData()` method itself.

And since you would be wanting to delete the movie altogether from the list on click of it, you'd need to send the id or in your case, the index of the movie along with it, like,

```html
<td><button onclick="deleteRow(${i});">Delete</button></td>
```

and create a handler accordingly, like so,

```js
function deleteRow(i) {
  movieData.splice(i, 1);
  loadTableData(movieData);
}
```

As you can see this works. But the `loadTableData(movieData)` function call at the end takes care of refreshing the UI, but it doesn't really consider the current sorted view. That I guess you should be able to figure out or handle as per your discretion.

```js
'use strict'

let movieData = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Network", "genre": "Comedy|Drama", "rating": "68.22" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Kommissarie Späck", "genre": "Comedy", "rating": "30.65" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Pirate, The", "genre": "Adventure|Comedy|Musical|Romance", "rating": "98.22" },
    { "id": 4, "name": "Mary and Martha", "genre": "Drama", "rating": "11.15" },
    { "id": 5, "name": "Four Days in September (O Que É Isso, Companheiro?)", "genre": "Drama", "rating": "20.35" },
    { "id": 6, "name": "Sibling Rivalry", "genre": "Comedy", "rating": "5.91" },
    { "id": 7, "name": "Alice in Wonderland", "genre": "Adventure|Children|Fantasy", "rating": "52.69" },
    { "id": 8, "name": "Dead Weekend", "genre": "Comedy|Sci-Fi", "rating": "30.84" },
    { "id": 9, "name": "Top Hat", "genre": "Comedy|Musical|Romance", "rating": "60.06" },
    { "id": 10, "name": "Cleopatra", "genre": "Drama|Romance|War", "rating": "65.39" },
    { "id": 11, "name": "For All Mankind", "genre": "Documentary", "rating": "73.24" },
    { "id": 12, "name": "Messiah of Evil", "genre": "Horror", "rating": "28.9" },
    { "id": 13, "name": "Princess and the Pirate, The", "genre": "Adventure|Comedy|Romance", "rating": "20.41" },
    { "id": 14, "name": "Restrepo", "genre": "Documentary|War", "rating": "71.18" },
    { "id": 15, "name": "Return to the Blue Lagoon", "genre": "Adventure|Romance", "rating": "67.92" },
    { "id": 16, "name": "Convoy", "genre": "Action|Comedy|Drama", "rating": "22.53" },
    { "id": 17, "name": "Perfect", "genre": "Drama|Romance", "rating": "86.25" },
    { "id": 18, "name": "Son of Babylon (Syn Babilonu)", "genre": "Drama", "rating": "26.54" },
    { "id": 19, "name": "Heaven and Earth (Ten to Chi to)", "genre": "Action|Adventure|Drama|War", "rating": "69.39" },
    { "id": 20, "name": "Carcasses", "genre": "Documentary", "rating": "3.72" },
    { "id": 21, "name": "Repentance", "genre": "Drama|Horror|Thriller", "rating": "55.21" },
    { "id": 22, "name": "Loose Change: Second Edition", "genre": "Documentary|Mystery", "rating": "72.22" },
    { "id": 23, "name": "Resurrection Man", "genre": "Drama|Thriller", "rating": "74.68" },
    { "id": 24, "name": "Green Card", "genre": "Comedy|Drama|Romance", "rating": "35.28" },
    { "id": 25, "name": "Micki + Maude", "genre": "Comedy", "rating": "2.02" },
    { "id": 26, "name": "Rover, The", "genre": "Crime|Drama", "rating": "18.73" },
    { "id": 27, "name": "Dark Horse (Voksne mennesker)", "genre": "Comedy|Drama|Romance", "rating": "28.19" },
    { "id": 28, "name": "Street Thief", "genre": "Crime|Documentary", "rating": "67.11" },
    { "id": 29, "name": "Woman In Berlin, A (Anonyma - Eine Frau in Berlin)", "genre": "Drama|War", "rating": "13.85" },
    { "id": 30, "name": "Expendables, The", "genre": "Action|Adventure|Thriller", "rating": "92.78" },
 
];


//Toggle Sort

function sortTable(n) {
    let table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
    table = document.getElementById("tableData");
    switching = true;
    dir = 'asc';
    while (switching) {
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;
        for (i = 0; i < (movieData.length - 1); i++) {
            shouldSwitch = false;
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[n];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName('td')[n];
            if (dir == 'asc') {
                if (parseFloat(x.innerHTML) > parseFloat(y.innerHTML)) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (dir == 'desc') {
                if (parseFloat(x.innerHTML) < parseFloat(y.innerHTML)) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
            switchcount++;
        } else {
            if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                dir = "desc";
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
};

//Add content to the table
function addTableRow() {
    let table = document.getElementById('tableData');
    let txt = '';
    let movieNameInput = document.getElementById('movieName').value;
    let movieGenreInput = document.getElementById('movieGenre').value;
    let movieRatingInput = document.getElementById('movieRating').value;

    let row = table.insertRow();
    txt = txt + `<tr><td>${movieNameInput}</td><td>${movieGenreInput}</td><td>${movieRatingInput}</td></tr>`;
    row.innerHTML = txt;


}

function deleteRow(i) {
  movieData.splice(i, 1);
  loadTableData(movieData);
}


window.onload = () => {
    loadTableData(movieData);
}



function loadTableData(movieData) {
    let tableBody = document.getElementById('tableData');
    let txt = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < movieData.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + `<tr><td>${movieData[i].name}</td><td>${movieData[i].genre}</td><td>${movieData[i].rating}</td><td><button onclick="deleteRow(${i});">Delete</button></td></tr>`;
    }
    tableBody.innerHTML = txt
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2f2;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: rgb(250, 241, 231);
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 40px auto;
}

tr,
th {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 16px Z;
}

th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: bisque;
    background-color: #444
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: rgba(15, 85, 6, 0.438);
}

tr:hover {
    color: whitesmoke;
    background-color: rgba(82, 79, 78, 0.568);
    transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

.name {
    background: #444;
}

.genre {
    background-color: rgba(240, 101, 50, 0.411)
}

.toggler {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgba(245, 62, 6, 0.658);
}

.addremove {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color: coral;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Tabela</title>

</head>

<!--TABLE-->

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="name">Name</th>
                    <th class="genre">Genre</th>
                    <th class="toggler" onclick="sortTable(2)">Rating</th>
                    <th class="name">Action</th>
                    
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="tableData">

            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>

    <br>


    <!--ADD/REMOVE BUTTON-->
   
   <div class="addremove">

        Name : <input type="text" name="text" id="movieName"> 
        Genre : <input type="text" name="text" id="movieGenre"> 
        Rating : <input type="text" name="rating" id="movieRating">


        <button onclick="addTableRow();">Add</button>

    </div>

    </div>







    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this :

[image]

Add your HTML code (table)

Comment: Can you show the HTML code and specially what you changed ?